# Raspberry Pi playing music from Spotify automatically

Tags: python, automation, raspberry-pi, spotify

I am trying to figure out how to get a Raspberry Pi to play music from Spotify when the user comes home. I have some python code that will let the Raspberry Pi know the user is home, now I just need to the music to play. I am wanting to know if this can be possible in anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you could do it as far as I know, but both have some inconveniences.

There are two Python libraries called [libspotify](https://github.com/mopidy/libspotify-archive) (an official spotify library) and [pyspotify](https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify) (which is a wrapper for the first one). However, libspotify is not maintained anymore, a problem which also affects pyspotify. I'm not sure whether they still work; but if they do, using an unmaintained library is not really a good idea.

The only officially supported alternative you could use is the [Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/). However, the SDK is a client-side Javascript library; which means that you would need to use to a different tecnology, at least for that part of your project.

You could make a web app and run it locally on your pi (or even package it as an [electron](https://electronjs.org/) app) which your Python program sends a signal to when it should play (the logic of what to play would probably be better in the web app).

Anyway, if you end up using that approach, it would probably be better to move all the logic to the web app, including knowing when someone has arrived.

Comment: that does sound like a good idea. I did read though that the token given for requesting only lasts an hour until I would need to renew it. I wonder if there is a way around that?